# Kubernetes Execute Script Before Container Start

Tags: kubernetes

I want to execute script before I run my container

If I execute script in container like that

```
      containers:
        - name: myservice
          image: myservice.azurecr.io/myservice:1.0.6019912
          volumeMounts:
          - name: secrets-store-inline
            mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
            readOnly: true
          command:
            - '/bin/bash'
            - '-c'
            - 'ls /mnt/secrets-store;'
```

then that command replaces my entrypoint and the pod exits. How can I execute command but then start the container after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to do this is too use [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) but I'm unsure what you're trying to run before you run the `ENTRYPOINT`.

You can apply the same volume mounts in the init container(s), if the init work requires changing state of the mounted file system content.

Another solution may be to run the `ENTRYPOINT`'s command as the last statement in the script.

Comment: Thanks for answering DazWilkin!

How can I find what is the exact ENTRYPOINT command? Isn't it inside the Docker file? How to call docker? What is the command or how to find it?

Comment: Perhaps I can add the command to Docker instead! Instead of kubernetes, thanks!

Comment: You can `docker inspect [[IMAGE]]:[[TAG]]` to see the commands (layers) in an image. However, it sounds as though you did not create the image and then (!?) you should probably not change the image ("you break it, you pay for it") and would be better either using an init container or scripting running the image.

Comment: Thanks Daz, that helped me find the command! The Dockefile idea was not a very smart one though, because I need to run not during build but during run Thanks you!